# Can't log object details from parsed JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have no problem logging the following:

```
<h1>Order List</h1>

<ul> 
    <%orders.forEach(function(order){%>
        <li><%console.log(order.ShippingAddress);%></li>
    <%});%>
</ul>
```

But when I attempt to log this:

```
<h1>Order List</h1>

<ul> 
    <%orders.forEach(function(order){%>
        <li><%console.log(order.ShippingAddress.Name);%></li>
    <%});%>
</ul>
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
```

I must be overlooking something very simple because "Name" clearly exists... I am just not setting something up correctly. Any ideas?

Here is what the data looks like for each 'order':

```
{ AmazonOrderId: '99999',
  PurchaseDate: 'date',
  LastUpdateDate: 'date',
  OrderStatus: 'Shipped',
  FulfillmentChannel: 'MFN',
  SalesChannel: 'Amazon.com',
  ShipServiceLevel: 'Std US D2D Dom',
  ShippingAddress: 
    { Name: 'name here',
      AddressLine1: 'address here',
      City: 'city',
      StateOrRegion: 'state',
      PostalCode: '999999',
      CountryCode: 'US' }
```

I can get this to work using pHp the following way:

```
<?php
    $string = file_get_contents('./data/store.json');
    $data = json_decode($string, true);


    foreach($data[ListOrdersResult][Orders][Order] as $order) {
        print_r("<li>".$order[ShippingAddress][Name]."</li>");
    }
?>
```

Comment: It should work perfectly. Please check if there is any order object with no shipping information or ShippingAdress object

Comment: This was the issue. Thank you! Any idea why php works without checking for a shipping address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your first snippet actually contains a ShippingAddress with data?

There might 1 specific order (or more) with no shipping information? Try dropping `console.log(order.AmazonOrderId)` just before trying to display the Name and you'll see what order it's stopping on.

Comment: Ah! You're the best, I guess I wasn't paying enough attention. I just added if(order.ShippingAddress) {console.log(order.ShippingAddress.Name)}; and it worked. Thank you. I guess php doesn't require that check.